# How to set the current active page as s header location in PHP?

Tags: php, html

In my web-site there's 2 pages. Home & My Posts. Both pages have a option to post posts. Currently it's working like when I post something from My Posts it will re-direct me back to home. No difference in home.
But I need it to stay on the same page where user posted the post.(If posted from Home stay in Home page. Posted from My Posts stay in My Posts).
This is my current code.

```
if ($result == TRUE) {
    header("Location:../home.php");
} else {
    header("Location:../home.php?failed");
}
```

Comment: You need to send query parameter with name (?page=home) and pass parameter to Location:.../{$_GET["page"]}.php, or you can use any router ofc

Comment: _"But I need it to stay on the same page"_ - well then why _go_ anywhere else in the first place? If you put your code that processes the form submission into a separate file, then you can include that at the start of both your existing files. And then you just leave the forms' action attributes empty, so that they will each submit to the same URL you are already on automatically.